# Calculus book advice

Tags: calculus, reference-request, soft-question

I'm reading Thomas Calculus now but I don't think it includes Mellin transform or  Riemann-Stieltjes integration... Can you recommend an advanced calculus book which includes all of this stuff?

Comment: I can suggest you Michael Spivak Calculus, https://archive.org/details/Calculus_643; it definetly includes Riamann integration but I am not sure about Mellin trans forms.